# How do I write my own Django model update signal?

Tags: django

I'm currently using a the pre_save django signals and it works fine when calling the save method on a model. How do I write an update signal to a model?  Django doesn't seem to have an update signal built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both creates and updates are considered saves, so they use the same signals.

Comment: That's strange, I'm calling update() and the pre_save signal is not being triggered.

Comment: `QuerySet.update()`? That's why then. `QuerySet` does not usually emit signals, since its methods affect the database, not models.